# Filter on Showcolumn & distinct, inside my Power Apps formula

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, formula

I have this formula which is working correctly:

```
ClearCollect(
     colUniqueDates,
     AddColumns(
         RenameColumns(
             Distinct(
                 'Grant Applications',
                 Title
             ),
             "Result",
             "Title"
         ).Title,
         "Level",
         1
     )
 );
```

but I wanted to add filter to is, as follow:

[image]

but I got name is not recognized error. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
ClearCollect(
     colUniqueDates,
     AddColumns(
         RenameColumns(
             Distinct(
                 Filter('Grant Applications', CurrentState="1" || CurrentState="0"),
                 Title
             ),
             "Result",
             "Title"
         ).Title,
         "Level",
         1
     )
 );
```